# jQuery UI Sortable Position using < input >

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

This table http://jsfiddle.net/rp4fV/477/ has input element that I need to sort the rows adding number and getting result as dragging, for example if i input 2 to row 4 the row 4 getting up automatically to replace the row 2 and all rows get sorting depend on the new changes, is there any suggestion how to done that ?
i know how to do that using drag but using input i have no idea how to done that.

the reason to it, that there is many rows and when drag sometimes i can't recognise the correct place.

## code:

```
$('td, th', '#sortFixed').each(function () {
  var cell = $(this);
 cell.width(cell.width());
});
$('#sortFixed tbody').sortable().disableSelection();
```

Comment: So you want to be able to set the sort based on the Text input, or swap the position based on the index number entered?

Answer (score 1):

you need to bind input element to `oninput` event after that do the actions

```js
// Fix the width of the cells

$('td, th', '#sortFixed').each(function() {
  var cell = $(this);
  cell.width(cell.width());
});

$('#sortFixed tbody').sortable().disableSelection();

$('body').on('input', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
  $('tbody tr').removeClass('marker');
  var currentEl = $(this);
  var index = parseInt(currentEl.val());
  if (index <= $('input[type="text"]').length) {
    currentEl.attr('value', index)
    var oldLoc = currentEl.parent().parent()
    var newLoc = $('tbody tr').eq(index-1)
    newLoc.addClass('marker')
    var newLocHtml = newLoc.html()
    newLoc.html(oldLoc.html()).hide().fadeIn(1200);
    oldLoc.html(newLocHtml)
  }
})
```

```css
tbody tr {
  cursor: move
}

.marker {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-dist@1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table id="sortFixed" class="grid">
    <caption>Kurt Vonnegut novels</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Order</th><th>Year</th><th>Title</th><th>Grade</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id='ordem_0' name="order"></td><td>1969</td><td>Slaughterhouse-Five</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id='ordem_1' name="order"></td><td>1952</td><td>Player Piano</td><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id='ordem_2' name="order"></td><td>1963</td><td>Cat's Cradle</td><td>A+</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id='ordem_3' name="order"></td><td>1973</td><td>Breakfast of Champions</td><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" id='ordem_4' name="order"></td><td>1965</td><td>God Bless You, Mr. Rosewater</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be more complicated than you wanted, but I hope this helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9aes8omr/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function showIndex(tb) {
    var fields = $(tb).find("input[name='order']");
    console.log(fields);
    fields.each(function(ind, el) {
      console.log(ind, el);
      $(el).val(ind + 1);
    });
  }

  function spliceRow(tb, r, i) {
    var ind = i - 1;
    var ln = $("tr", tb).length;
    var rows = [];
    $("tr", tb).each(function(ind, el) {
      rows.push(el);
    });
    rows.splice(ind, 0, r);
    tb.html("");
    $.each(rows, function(k, v) {
      tb.append(v);
    });
  }
  // Fix the width of the cells
  $('td, th', '#sortFixed').each(function() {
    var cell = $(this);
    cell.width(cell.width());
  });

  $('#sortFixed tbody').sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    update: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Sort Update.");
      showIndex($(this));
    }
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortFixed tbody").on("change", "input[name='order']", function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    var orig = me.parents("tr");
    var row = orig.clone();
    var t = parseInt(me.val());
    console.log(t, row);
    orig.remove();
    spliceRow($("#sortFixed tbody"), row, t);
    $("#sortFixed tbody").sortable("refresh");
    showIndex($("#sortFixed tbody"));
  });
});
```

If you create an array of the html rows, you can then use `.splice()`. If you want to use sortable and manually enter indexes, the above code does this. You can drag them and it will resort or you can enter a number and it will change position (and also refresh sortable).

This means in the end, you can use `.sortable("serialize")` or `.sortable("toArray")` as you like.

Hope that helps.